# how do you log if a query hit the cache with ApolloClient?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo

Consider the following, using Apollo Client's Query Component:

```
  <Query {...props} query={NOTEBOOK_QUERY} variables={{ id: props.notebookId }} >
    {result => props.children(result)}
  </Query>
```

the first time this runs i expect it to be a network call, and the second time I expect it to hit the cache.

**Is there tooling that I can plug into to print out if it was a cache hit or miss, and what key was used?**

Thanks!!

Comment: Relevant [issue in the apollo client GH repo](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-feature-requests/issues/87). One commenter [mentions](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-feature-requests/issues/87#issuecomment-532870019) hooking in to the hidden [`__actionHookForDevTools` API](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client-devtools/blob/cb0e7f47a0df4b4866aaf24c6869a3d5b8310a5b/src/backend/hook.js#L84-L91).

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [Apollo Dev Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/apollo-client-developer-t/jdkknkkbebbapilgoeccciglkfbmbnfm?hl=en-US) in Chrome, you can see the queries that have been cached in the Apollo Link State and it should show you whether it hit a result stored in the link state or went back to the database.